# Which .apk file should i upload on google play, signed apk or in projects-->build

Tags: android

i want to upload my app in google play market, but i am confused,
which .apk file should i use to upload, 1) Build-->signed apk--  ........
and 2)select projects from to left corner in android studio-->app-->outputs--> .apk file

One more thing , when i am creating signed .apk from build menu-> signed apk

after filling all the details...
android studio... shows an error....it does not recognize raw folder and its audio file
what i do , to remove this error
please suggest me.........

Comment: You pick the first one, the signed apk. For error, it's better you create a new question and post exact error that you get so people can help you.

Comment: You need to upload signed apk. You will get password, tag ..  something important. You have to save this information.When you are going to increase your version you will have to sign your apk with same password, tag ..

Answer (score 0):

You should choose former, the signed .apk to upload to Google, the other one is for the debugging purposes.

here, this one. -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/crswm.png

Also, I would suggest you to clean, rebuild project once before generating signed .apk, although its done on build.

Also, kindly provide the exact error you are getting while building the signed apk.